# XMLHttpRequest status code is always 0

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to operate on all ajax requests and specifically handle 409s, but my status code is *always* 0 even though FireFox debugger will clearly show me a 409.

JS Code

```
(function(open) {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
    if(this.status === 409)
        console.log("Conflict 409")
    open.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

I can extremely easily generate 409s with my server code. I see FireFox and Chrome showing 409s. But `this.status` is always 0, even on 400s. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `status` is only set after `send` is called, and `send` can only be called after `open`. Thus, `open` never sees a status other than zero.

Comment: I see. Can I operate immediately in send, or do I need to wait for some event or readystate ? I've tried operating immediately on send and my status is still 0.

Comment: No, that happens even later. If you just want to run some code when a 409 happens, you can add an event listener via `this.addEventListener('readystatechange', ...)` and check for status 409 there. If you want to prevent all other listeners from running on a 409... that's gonna be more complex, and require you to hook a bunch of methods and properties.

Comment: All I am going to do is a `window.location = ...` when I see any 409

Comment: Ah. In that case you don't have to bother with the other event listeners, as their actions will have no consequences. :)

Comment: Perfect. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking status before the request has finished.

You can use [xhook](https://github.com/jpillora/xhook) library to intercept XHR responses.

Example:

```
xhook.after((request, response) => {
  if (response.status === 409) {
    console.log("Conflict 409")
  }
})
```